# How to resolve Promise after mongoose function without async await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, promise

I got stuck a place where I need to get proper response after creating a record to mongoDB using mongoose. Its giving me response in < Promise > but I cant use async / await to resolve the promise. Here is my code:

In controller file I am calling a function like this here I can't use async / await in this function.

```
let response = Category.createCategory(categoryName);
need response for further activity or should be return but not waiting for response
```

In common function file I have below code:   // can use async / await

```
createCategory(category) {
  let data = {
     clientCategory: category
  }
  return this._createObj(data);
}
```

In DB file:   // can use async / await

```
_createObj(obj) {
  return Category.create(obj);
}
```

We can use async / await but not there where I am getting final response. I also tried to use new Promise and Promise.then as well but not getting response. I need response and need to use after that. Any idea how I can get proper response without async / await. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: "*I cant use async / await*" - why not? If your environment does not support the syntax, you can still use a transpiler.

Comment: If you cannot use `await`, you have to use `.then()`: `Category.createCategory(categoryName).then(response => {…});`

Comment: "*should […] not [be] waiting for response*" - that is impossible. The response isn't available immediately, there's no way around waiting for it.